# Datetime Displaying Incorrectly?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to compare the DateTime of two files and if they dont match then just overwrite the old one(destination) with the new one(source). None the less, the DateTime when debugging shows up as "12/31/1600 6:00:00 PM" has anybody else had this problem?

Also, heres my code:

```
DateTime srcTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(strSrcFile);

//loop through the list to compare the datetime of each file
foreach (var item in targetfiles)
{
DateTime dstTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(item.ToString());

if (srcTime != dstTime)
{
File.Copy(sourcePath, Path.Combine(dstTargetPath, Path.GetFileName(strSrcFile)), true);
}
}
```

Edit: Nevermind everyone, I fixed it. I didn't realise you had to enter the full path rather than just the file name itself. *Doh*. Thanks for your time!

Comment: _"The DateTime"_ which `DateTime`?

Comment: what is the current culture info?

Comment: Check the value of item.ToString(),  is it a file path or is it just an object name?  Do both srcTime and dstTime show the year 1600?

Answer (score 4):

Please [**read the documentation for File.GetLastWriteTime**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getlastwritetime.aspx)

> If the file described in the path parameter does not exist, this method returns 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.) Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), **adjusted to local time**.

Take note of the last part... that's why you're seeing a slightly different date and time.

Comment: How does one even "adjust local time"?

Comment: UTC is considered universal time and it mostly synonymous with the Greenwich Mean Time in England.  "Adjusted to local time" means that if it is 12:00 midnight in Greenwich, it is 6:00 PM where you are.

Comment: @user2619395 I believe Grax answered your question. Is there anything further you would like answered?